# SQL - Select all items in a radius

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to make a SQL statement which provides me a list with candidates within a certain area. I like to make a selection based on (A) location of a job and (B) location of a candidate. The SQL statement needs to work on a MariaDB server.

I did the homework but can't figure out how to get this done. I believe the code needs to be something like this. But, i'm not quite sure how this works.

DESCRIPTION
Input: Job-id, radius
Calls: candidate-table (id’s, location), job-table (id’s, location)
Output: list of candidates within a radius

Implementation

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE calc_distance (IN job_id_var data_type, IN radius_var FLOAT, OUT cand_list)

SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ‘this code…’

BEGIN
/* Table with candidate-job combination and relevant characteristics (distance between the two) */

DECLARE @result1 TABLE (job_id INT, cand_id INT, job_x DOUBLE, job_y DOUBLE, cand_x DOUBLE, cand_y DOUBLE, dist DOUBLE)

SET @job_x = (SELECT job_x FROM job_table WHERE job_id = job_id_var)
SET @job_y = (SELECT job_y FROM job_table WHERE job_id = job_id_var)

INSERT INTO @result1 (cand_id, cand_x, cand_y)
SELECT a, b, c
FROM cand_table;

UPDATE @result1
SET job_id = job_id_var, job_x = @job_x, job_y = @job_y, dist = SQRT(POW(cand_x - job_x,2) + POW(cand_y - job_y,2))

SELECT * as cand_list
FROM @result
WHERE dist <= radius_var

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to process single job_id. I would first limit candidates by x and y distance (resulting in square, not circle) - this can be made, using simple query; in same query you can calculate the real distance and filter your candidates aftrewards somewhat. Much less work needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I found my answer in this:

**SELECT** contractor.id,

(3959 * acos( cos( radians( *51.5318464* ) ) * cos( radians( *address.latitude* ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( *4.4287569*) ) + sin( radians( *51.5318464* ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )

**AS** distance

**FROM** address

**INNER JOIN** contractor **on** address.id **=** contractor.address_id

**HAVING** distance **<** 20

**ORDER BY** distance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works:  `DECLARE @result1 TABLE ...` -- In general you cannot do substitutions without `prepare` and `execute`.

The entire procedure can be done in a single `SELECT`.  In general, you should strive for such.  This is because SQL thinks in performing things on sets (tables), not a single thing at a time.

`OUT cand_list` -- `OUT` values can only be scalars.  However the entire procedure can produce effectively the same as a `SELECT`, namely a bunch of rows and columns.  So the entire Stored Proc becomes only:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM job_table
    WHERE Distance(job_x, job_y, cand_x, cand_y) < radius_var
```

If you want, you could tack on `ORDER BY Distance(...)` to get the nearest first.

Well, OK, now we need to define a simple Stored Function named `Distance` that takes two pairs of x and y, returning a FLOAT.

Caution:  x and y work for some situations, but they don't work well for latitude and longitude.  Longitudes need to be divided by `cos(latitude)` to adjust.